# Rails not rendering partials

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My models has users who can create projects. I'm trying to render a partial inside the show action of my user controller.

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= render(:partial => "projects/new_project") %>
<% end %>
```

This is the code for the show method

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @project = Project.new
    @characters = Character.sorted
    @personalities = Personality.sorted
    @industries = Industry.sorted
    @project_types = ProjectType.sorted
  end
```

And this is my helper method current_user

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

helper_method :current_user
```

This is the partial view _new_projects

```
<div class="row">
    <div class= "col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5">

        <% form_for @project do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field(:title, placeholder: "Give your project a name", :class => 'form-control') %>

            <%= f.select(:project_type_id, @project_types.map {|n| [n.project_type_name, n.id]}, {}, :class => 'form-control') %>

            <%= f.select(:industry_id, @industries.map {|n| [n.industry_name, n.id]},{}, :class => 'form-control') %>

            <%= f.select(:character_id, @characters.map {|n| [n.character_name, n.id]},{}, :class => 'form-control') %>

            <%= f.select(:personality_id, @personalities.map {|n| [n.personality_name, n.id]},{}, :class => 'form-control') %>

            <%= f.text_area(:description, :class => 'form-control') %>

            <div class='padding-top'></div>

            <%= submit_tag("Post project", :class => 'btn btn-success btn-sm sniglet') %>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page renders blank without the partial

Comment: Are you sure `session[:user_id]` is set?

Comment: Can you share the `projects/new_project` partial. Also, are you sure that current_user is set when you are trying this code?

Comment: @Kirti please see edits.

Comment: @Clockwork Let us discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know the problem without more information. But, judging by the limited code you provided a few things pique my interest:

1. Perhaps `current_user` is evaluating to `false` and the partial is not being rendered?
2. Why have the `current_user` check in the view? Why not limit the action to signed in users at the controller level?
3. Perhaps your partial expects a `Project` instance, and it's not being passed?

I would be helpful to see the controller, the partial, and the `current_user` code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add temporary log for current_user value:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  Rails.logger.info("!!!#{@current_user}")
end
```

and you will see your problem. Also here is small tip about if in template:

```
<%= render(:partial => "projects/new_project") if current_user %>
```

reads better as it seems for me.